# AWS - install python packages while deploying EC2 server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i am currently working on a project where I need to deploy python application on my EC2 instance. I cannot seem to figure out how to install packages on my EC2 instance during application installation. I have tried installation via "requirements.txt" file

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.22
```

as well as via .ebextenstion/01_packages.config file that looks as following:

```
packages:
    yum:
        mysql-connector-python: '8.0.22'
        requests: '2.24.0'
```

BUT every time is deploy new version of my application i get an error and updated list of packages is not installed.

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: `ebextenstion` is for elastic beanstalk, not for regular instances. So you are using EB or just normal plain EC2 instance?

Comment: I am using EB. Deployment is done via eb deploy.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: "environment deployment unsuccessfull" for more information ease go to eb-instance.log. When I look into log file - it says something is wrong with my config file where packages are defined. But it does not say what exactly.

Comment: Which EB platform for python are you using?

Comment: I believe it is python 3.4

Comment: Possible platforms are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating setup.config file in my .ebextentions, where I configured command to install required packages.

```
commands:
    install_requests:
        command: "pip install requests"
    install_wheel:
        command: "pip install wheel"
    install_mysql-connector-python:
        command: "pip install mysql-connector-python"
```

Answer (score 1):

I **verified** on EB `Python 3.7 AL2 version 3.1.4` that the following `requirements.txt` works:

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.22
requests==2.24.0
```

Thus if you have other issues, they are not caused by the `requirements.txt` on that platform.

Comment: Once requirements txt is uploaded into EC2 instance do you need to run some additional scripts to install packages?

Comment: @Sky21.86 You bundle `requirements.txt` with your deployment zip. You don't have to do anything. EB will find the file and install the requirements.

Comment: as suggested i have added requirements.txt in the root of my project. initiated "eb create" command via terminal. Instance creation went successfully: deployment generated 2021-01-04 14:28:19    INFO    Instance deployment successfully generated a 'Procfile'. However when i run "pip3 list" i do not see mysql-connector-python installed on my EC2 instance